# Como sumar 2 Time Selector

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Con el método `Substract()` se obtiene la diferencia de 2 `TimeSelector`, ahora quisiera saber como hallar la suma.

si la diferencia se halla asi:

```
Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFin.Subtract(horaInicio)
```

Lo que busco es sumar los dos valores, algo como por ejemplo:

```
Dim suma As TimeSpan = horaInicio + horaFin
```

Comment: TimeSpan tiene un método Add, no se si sea el caso pero recuerdo que VS con VB, por defecto el Intellisense no mostrado todo los métodos (la ultima vez que sufrí con vb fue con VS2005), https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timespan.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Que resultado esperas al sumar 2 `DateTime`? La resta es clara, y te da el tiempo que hay entre dos fechas, pero si sumas dos fechas,que esperas que haga?

Comment: El usuario selecciona un rango de tiempo T, si por ejemplo ese rango es de  5 horas, el usuario debe justificar 2 horas en la actividad  A1 y 3 horas en la actividad A2, luego la suma de las actividades debe ser igual al tiempo seleccionado inicialmente.    T=A1+A2

Comment: En todo caso, o al seleccionar la actividad el usuario selecciona el tiempo empleado, o selecciona la hora de inicio y hara de fin de cada actividad. En ambos casos, lo que se debe sumar es **la cantidad de tiempo empleado en cada actividad**, no la suma de las fechas

Comment: El proceso es así: El usuario selecciona cuantas horas trabajo en el dia y debe distribuir esas horas en varias actividades, lo que se requiere es que luego que haga las distribuciones de horas justificandolas con su respectiva actividad, al final los tiempos de cada actividad corresponda al total de horas que está reportando al inicio.

Comment: Muy bien. Con lo cual el proceso será obtener las horas que trabajó en cada actividad y sumarlas. En ningun caso es `horaInicio + horaFin` sino mas bien `Dim tiempoTarea1 As TimeSpan =(horaFin1-horaInicio1)`,`Dim tiempoTarea1 As TimeSpan =tiempoTarea2(horaFin2-horaInicio1)`.. y al final `Dim tiempoTotal As TimeSpan =tiempoTarea1+tiempoTarea2...`